# How to keep linked list head from changing?

Tags: c, char, structure

I'm trying to create a linked list structure to store data.  The head of the linked list seems to be updating somehow.  I have the following code.  I can't seem to figure out how put char array data into a node and keep it from updating when the address to said char array's data updates.

The following code prints out whatever string is passed into the processStr function. How do I keep head from updating ?

```
//Linked List Structure 
mainNode *head = NULL;

//take and store word in data structure 
void processStr(char *str){

    //char array
   char strArray[sizeof(str)+1];

    //stores lower case string
    char strLower[strlen(str)];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; str[i]; i++)
            strLower[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    strLower[i] = '\0';

    //printf("%s : ", strLower);

    //Starts Linked List
    if(head == NULL){

            mainNode *mainPtr = (mainNode *)malloc(sizeof(mainNode));
            nameNode *namePtr = (nameNode *)malloc(sizeof(nameNode));

            mainPtr->name = strLower;
            mainPtr->numOccurances = 1;
            mainPtr->next = NULL;
            mainPtr->nextName = namePtr;

            namePtr->name = strArray;
            namePtr->next = NULL;

            head = mainPtr;

    }

    printf("%s : " , head->name);
}
```

Comment: you are assigning `mainPtr` to `head` every time you call `processStr`. Also note that `str` is a character pointer. `sizeof str` will be either `4` or `8` depending on your machine. Maybe you meant `char strArray[strlen(str)+1];`.

Comment: How is mainPtr being assigned to head every time I call processStr ? After the first assignment head is no longer NULL and that conditional statement is not entered again.

Comment: this piece of code will change head only once, when head == NULL, your problem most probably somewhere else. btw, this is one of the reasons not to use global variales when you don't have to.

Comment: yeah I didn't use it by choice it's for a homework assignment.  void processStr is supposed to only have the char *str input and add str into the data structure.  I didn't know any other way to have the data structure updated short of making it global.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the pointers `mainPtr->name` and `namePtr->name` to variables `strLower` and `strArray` that are declared locally in `processStr()`. That means after that function returns, any access to these pointers results in undefined behaviour. You could do sth. like

```
 mainPtr->name = strdup( strLower );
```

instead to allocate memory for the strings.

Btw.: `strLower` must also be declared as `char strLower[strlen(str)+1];`

Comment: is strdup part of the standard c libraries? im getting an implicit declaration warning.

Comment: This change has worked.  Just produces warnings where I'm using strdup

Comment: `#include` the appropriate header file string.h

Comment: string.h has been included

Comment: Then you should at least not get an implicit declaration warning, as string.h declares `strdup()`- What exactly is the compiler warning?

Comment: I changed the declarations as follows
    //duplicates string;
    char *dupStr = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    strcpy(dupStr, str);

    //lowercase duplicate;
    char *lowerStr = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0;str[i];i++)
     lowerStr[i] = tolower(str[i]);

Comment: that's alright too, should be quite exactly what `strdup()` does internally (don't bother about the format, I have understood :-))

Answer (score 0):

The above code will only run once only which will add information to head only once. If you want to add more information in case of second run then add code for else condition. Example:-

```
if ( head == NULL ) {

   // code to insert data in case of first run
}else{

   // code to insert data for second run and so.....
}
```